# Intellij not able to identify Cucumber 5 groovy Steps

Tags: java, intellij-idea, groovy, cucumber

Intellij Community Edition 2020.1.3 is not able to recognize the steps which is already defined in stepdefinition.
I am using only cucumber-groovy, cucumber-core, cucumber-junit : all 5.1.3 Version.

I tried below and it is not working.

- Cucumber Groovy & Cucumber Java plugins are already installed
- No Substeps plugin installed

I am referring this project on github:  https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm-groovy/blob/main/examples/src/test/groovy/calc/CalculatorSteps.groovy

and my step definition contains code like below

```
import io.cucumber.datatable.DataTable
import groovy.transform.Field
import groovyx.net.http.ContentType
import groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException
import io.cucumber.groovy.EN
import io.cucumber.groovy.Hooks

this.metaClass.mixin(Hooks)
this.metaClass.mixin(EN)

def response
@Field evalResponse
@Field String DATABASENAME_CPGP01 = "011032"
@Field String DATABASENAME_CPGP02 = "011033"
@Field TetrisRESTClient tetrisRESTClient
@Field TetrisRESTClient jobRestClient
JemsTest.enableExtentReporting = false;

Before('@Functionality001') {
    initializeSetUp()
}

Given(/I am on XYZ screen/) { -> }

And(/below are the given inputs/) { DataTable arg1 -> }
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out myself. The Regex syntax used in Step Definition is that of Java and not Groovy which was causing problem. I overlooked this minor difference.

Answer (score 0):

For resolve this issue you should update your libraries.

If it is not help then try go through this tutorial: https://medium.com/@cheparsky/migration-cucumber-older-version-4-to-newer-version-6-133ffb60813d